# How to keep ReactiveCommand alive after exception?

Tags: c#, observable, reactiveui

I'm trying to use this snippet :

```
LinkCurrentMailToCase = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => MyAPI.AddMailToCase(CurrentMailItem, CurrentCase));

LinkCurrentMailToCase .ThrownExceptions.Select(ex => ex.Message).ToProperty(this, vm => vm.ErrorMessage, out errorMessage);
```

And then I bind a button to LinkCurrentMailToCase . This works fine until an exception is thrown, in which case my LinkCurrentMailToCase doesn't get called anymore.

From what I've read in different posts, this is the normal behaviour for an Observable, but i can't figure out how to set my ErrorMessage if an exception is thrown while keeping the Observable alive.

Comment: After struggling (getting used to this with reactiveui and its lack of samples/documentation), i figured i'd use Catch(Observable.Return(Unit)) along with ThrownExceptions like above.

Answer (score 0):

The command in your snippet can still be called again after it's failed, it's not necessary to use `Catch` for that. But if you subscribe to the command itself and it's failing it will end in the `OnError` callback (if you have one), besides piping through `ThrownExceptions`.

It all depends on how you call your command, if you use `BindCommand` or pipe the command using `InvokeCommand` from another observable it should work as described.

But if you use `<Command>.Execute().Subscribe()` and you don't register an `OnError` handler (or use `Catch` for example), the observable pipeline from the command will break.

Comment: Actually I BindCommand the LinkCurrentMailToCase command to a button, and it doesn't work anymore after it reaches ThrownException unless i use Catch.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case normally, could you share a more complete reproduction / project on GitHub for example?